# how can I send custom message from my in app-browser to my ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am trying to send a custom payload from my js inside my inAppBrowser to my ionic app. I already know how to send data to the inAppbrowser using:

```
iab.executeScript({code:`alert(2)`});
```

but sending data back is not properly documented, on the github site I saw:

```
inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('message', messageCallBack);
```

the above only shows how to make your ionic receive it, but does not show how the javascript is sending it. Please I need help on how to make the inAppbrowser send this custom message.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Rajasekar yes I did. Are you having issues with it too?

Comment: yes i am facing difficulties in sending message from my application to in-app browser. i need to send it multiple times (during multiple events). can you help

Comment: @Rajasekar look at my answer below and if that doesn't help you, please create a question with your exact issue and I will post a specific answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  ref: InAppBrowser;
  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {

  }

  openBlank() {

    var payload = JSON.stringify({
      "currency": "",
      "exp": "",
      "success_title": "",
      "success_message": ""
    })

    var init = false;
    
    var ref = this.iab.create('https://random.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
      if(!init){
        console.log(' jeffery received')
        //ref.executeScript({ code: "webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage('"+payload+"')" });
        ref.executeScript({ code: "jsFunction('" + payload + "');" });
        init = true;
      }
    });

    ref.on('message').subscribe((event) => {

      const postObject:any = event
       console.log(postObject.data.type)
       console.log(JSON.stringify(postObject.data))
    })

    ref.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
      if(init){
        var shouldClose = this.getUrlParameter(event.url.replace(/%22/g, "\""), "shouldClose");
        if(shouldClose){
          var data = this.getUrlParameter(event.url.replace(/%22/g, "\""), "data");
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
          ref.close();
        }
      }
    });
  }

   getUrlParameter = (url, name) => {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  }

  openSystem() {
    this.iab.create(`https://jamibot.com`, `_system`);
  }


}
```

Comment: @Rajasekar this should help

Comment: Thanks for your reply @oto-obong Eshiett. I want to understand one thing. Here "jsFunction" should be a global function inside external application. is that right ?.

Comment: @Rajasekar yes, that is a function inside the HTML page that was called by the inAppbrowser, in our case it is https://random.com/

Comment: Thanks for you support @Oto-Obong Eshiett

Comment: did you send the message from browser to app using javascript's `postMessage`. is it working for system browser too?

Answer (score 1):

If the child page being opened in App is under your control, you can put this into the webpage

inside webpage

```
window.parent.postMessage({msg : 'I am message'}, '*');
```

inside App

```
window.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log('event received in app', event);
}
```